# Trying to convert a hexadecimal timestamp into decimal with CAST in standard SQL BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

So I'm trying to extract timestamps from UUIDs like [this](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-extracting-timstamp-and-mac.html)

I get stuck on the step to convert my hexadecimal string into a decimal integer. From my understanding this should work:

`SELECT CAST("1e78c9e03144170" AS INT64) as hex_to_dec`

I'm expecting the answer: `136865943201620000`

But I get error:

> Error: Could not cast literal "1e78c9e03144170" to type INT64 at [1:13]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT hex_val, CAST(CONCAT('0x', hex_val) AS INT64) AS hex_to_dec
```

you can test it with below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1e78c9e03144170' hex_val
)
SELECT hex_val, CAST(CONCAT('0x', hex_val) AS INT64) AS hex_to_dec
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

and result is

```
Row     hex_val             hex_to_dec   
1       1e78c9e03144170     137232923942470000
```

Note: your expected result of `136865943201620000` is incorrect. Correct one is `137232923942470000`
You can validate it for example [`here`](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter)

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked great.